# Sending information with get and parse xml

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xml-parsing, get

I wrote a simple code to use XML files. If I use a link which ends with .xml, it work correctly. But when i changed the link with http://www.tbl.org.tr/xml.asp?Lig=Beko&Eylem=PD&sezon=2013-2014, it shows anything.

My code is below.

How can I solve this problem?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.tbl.org.tr/xml.asp?Lig=Beko&Eylem=PD&sezon=2013-2014", false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

        document.write("<table width='350' cellpadding='5'>");
        var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Siralama");
        document.write("<tr><td width='20'>");
        document.write("Sıra");
        document.write("</td><td width='290'>");
        document.write("Takım");
        document.write("</td><td width='20'>");
        document.write("O");
        document.write("</td><td width='20'>");
        document.write("G");
        for ( i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            document.write("<tr><td width='20'>");
            document.write(x[i].getAttribute('Sira'));
            document.write("</td><td width='290'>");
            var y = x[i].getAttribute('Takim');
            if (y.length == 15)
                document.write("<font color=red><b>" + x[i].getAttribute('Takim') + "</b></font>");
            else
                document.write(x[i].getAttribute('Takim'));
            document.write("</td><td width='20'>");
            document.write(x[i].getAttribute('O'));
            document.write("</td><td width='20'>");
            document.write(x[i].getAttribute('G'));

            document.write("</td></tr>");
        }
        document.write("</table>");
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: what's a `parse link`?

Comment: http://www.tbl.org.tr/xml.asp?Lig=Beko&Eylem=PD&sezon=2013-2014

don't we call them parse link? if not, sorry. what I mean is above.

Comment: I see xml...but still doesn't explain your problem...or what you are changing that causes code to fail, nor explain what a `parse link` is

Comment: if I use domain.com/abc.xml the code works.
when I use http://www.tbl.org.tr/xml.asp?Lig=Beko&Eylem=PD&sezon=2013-2014 it doesn't work.

Comment: that's a cross domain call   ...can't do that with ajax and xml. Have to either get data as jsonp( if other domain provides) or use a proxy on your server to get the xml

Comment: read up on `same origin policy`

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have enough reputation to comment I have to answer this.
Your problem is most likely caused by "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". The thing charlietfl said is in my opinion true. I just wanted to add that you might consider using something else than document.write as document.write allows the site you're loading the XML from to manipulate your website and to inject custom scripts. You should parse the code and create DOM-elements instead of writing them to the document.